# Setup two environments for flutter firebase (existing project)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to set development environment for my project to have a seperate Firebase app because now my app has been released and I want to add features and fix bugs without touching the original Firestore database until I finish and then switch to the original database

is there a way to do it?

I tried to create Firebase configure but it says will override the `google-services.json` and `GoogleService-info.plist`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For Android:

- create a folder "staging" at `/android/app/src` and put your `google-services.json` for dev
- create a folder "production" at `/android/app/src` and put your `google-services.json` for production
- in your `/android/app/build.graddle`:

add

```
task switchToStaging(type: Copy) {
    description = 'Switches to Staging google-services.json'
    from "src/staging"
    include "google-services.json"
    into "."
}

task switchToProduction(type: Copy) {
    description = 'Switches to Production google-services.json'
    from "src/production"
    include "google-services.json"
    into "."
}

afterEvaluate {
    processStagingDebugGoogleServices.dependsOn switchToStaging
    processStagingReleaseGoogleServices.dependsOn switchToStaging
    processProductionDebugGoogleServices.dependsOn switchToProduction
    processProductionReleaseGoogleServices.dependsOn switchToProduction
}
```

You can replace "staging" and "production" by your flavors name. When you will build it will copy `google-services.json` from the created folder to `/android/app`

For iOS:

- the same way as Android, create a folder `Firebase/staging` and `Firebase/production` at `Runner/Runner/` and put your respective GoogleService-Info.plist

then, (assuming you have created your scheme that match to your flavors name), in `Build Phases` section in xcode:

replace if statement with your needs

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug-production" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release-production" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]; then

cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/Firebase/production/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist"

elif [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug-profile" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release-profile" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Profile" ]; then

cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/Firebase/staging/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist"

elif [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug-staging" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release-staging" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug" ]; then

cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/Firebase/staging/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist"

fi
```